# How to store the value of cat command in the variable var?

Tags: unix

I'm trying to find the number of times a string is repeated in a file, at the same time i've to store it in a variable.

When i use the command (`cat filename | grep -c '123456789'`) , it displays the count correctly but when i use the below command it shows as command not found.

```
var =$(cat filename | grep -c '123456789')
echo $var
```

Can u let me know where i'm wrong ?

Comment: Do you need the single quotes around your search string for grep?

Comment: @Levon, single quotes around the regex for grep would only be required if the regex contains characters that would be interpreted by the shell, like `$` or `[` or `]`. As a very simple regex containing no special characters, `123456789` doesn't need to be quoted.

Answer (score 17):

Don't use spaces around the `=` sign:

```
var=$(cat filename | grep -c '123456789')
```

Read at least the [Bash Prog Intro Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html)

But you've got a useless use of `cat` so code simply

```
    var=$(grep -c '123456789' filename)
```

Answer (score 6):

Remember that grep can read the file directly.  You can avoid **[useless use of cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#cat)**.

In the example in your question, the ***command not found*** error occurs because of the space before the equals sign.  Try this instead:

```
var=$(grep -c '123456789' filename)
```

or if you're using bash:

```
read var < <(grep -c '123456789' filename)
```

or (for completeness) in csh/tcsh:

```
setenv var `grep -c '123456789' filename`
```

Comment: This works fine since because i'm directly inputting the data.    

    declare -a arr
    arr=( $(awk '/123456789/{print NR}' filename) )
    echo ${arr[0]}
    echo ${arr[*]}

    
Bt when i do as below, it doesn't work. Can u let me know how the parameter 'name' can be used int command below :
    
    echo  Enter your search string:  
    read name
    declare -a arr
    arr=( $(awk '/"$name"/{print NR}' filename )
    echo ${arr[0]}
    echo ${arr[*]}

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're asking based on this comment, possibly due to the mess made by SO's formatting.  If you need to add more detail to your question, please click the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10891817/edit) link under the question, make your changes, and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Using backquotes will also work:

```
varx=`( cat filename| grep -c '123456789' )`
```

I.e., the `$` is not required, you can assign the output of various commands to variables through the use of backquotes.

For instance:

```
$ pwd
/home/user99

$ cur_dir=`pwd`
$ echo $cur_dir
/home/user99
```

Comment: That works because you removed the space before the `=` ; you could have kept the `$(`...`)` notation (more readable, and *nestable*) instead of the backquotes

Comment: @ Levon : Isn't it necessary to use $ symbol in above command ?

Comment: @JackieJames Not necessary, the command works as shown, you can use the backquotes instead. I've used this both with bash and the tcsh. Did you run into problems trying this?

Comment: @ Levon :
varx=`( cat filename| grep -c `123456789' )`
echo $varx
It doesn't print anything.

Comment: @JackieJames Can you copy directly from my answer (I tested this, using a different file and grep string of course). What you just posted seem to miss the leading backquote, the single quote in front of the 1234, and it looks as if you have a space after the `=` ... Let me know

Comment: varx=`( cat filename| grep -c `123456789' )` 
echo $varx
./count1.sh: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `'' 
./count1.sh: line 3: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: @JackieJames Sorry, I can't explain why this isn't working for you and I think your posts are being mangled with the formatting so it's hard for me to know what exactly is being typed. I just posted another example (these are all cut-and-paste from a unix shell).